# Validate if column is adding a day row by row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, row

I have the following dataframe as an example (already ordered per `PERSON_NUMBER`):

```
                Date_From     Date_To PROPOSAL_REASON
PERSON_NUMBER                                        
3720081000     2008-01-04  2009-12-07           MEINC
3720081000     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           MEINC
3720081000     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           MEINC
3720081018     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           MEINC
3720081018     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           MEINC
3720081077     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           MEINC
3720081111     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           MEINC
3720081211     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           MEINC
3720081211     2019-06-01  2019-10-31           MEINC
```

I need to verify, per each employee (and each employee can have 1 or more records) if each line, the `Date_To` from the first record +1 day should be the `Date_From` of the second record meaning there should be no gap in days when the records where created.

For the employees that have this gap I want to filter and save them in another dataframe.

So, for example, from the give dataframe, I would expect the following output to create a column with this info (first row of the record always `OK`):

```
                Date_From     Date_To     CHECK_CONDITION
PERSON_NUMBER                                        
3720081000     2008-01-04  2009-12-07           OK
3720081000     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           WARNING
3720081000     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           OK
3720081018     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           OK
3720081018     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           OK
3720081077     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           OK
3720081111     2019-04-01  2019-10-31           OK
3720081211     2018-07-01  2019-03-31           OK
3720081211     2019-06-01  2019-10-31           WARNING
```

So, as you can see, the record where it says `WARNING` the `Date_From` value is not the previous `Date_To` value + 1 day

Comment: Hey you can grouby person number and then chek each group. You could do this iteratively or parse the dates and try something like group[date from][1:]==group[date to].shift(1) +. np.timedelta64('1D').

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: @komatiraju032 done!

Comment: @kubatucka added output to facilitate, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
# STEP 1
df['Date_To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_To'])
df['Date_From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_From'])

# STEP 2
df['count'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])

# STEP 3
m1 = df['Date_From'].sub(df['Date_To'].shift()).dt.days.eq(1)

# STEP 4
m2 = df['count'].eq(df.groupby(level=0)['count'].transform('first'))

# STEP 5
df1 = df.assign(CHECK_CONDITION=np.where(m1 | m2, 'OK', 'WARNING')).drop('count', 1)
```

Explanation:

STEP 1: Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `Date_To` & `Date_From` column to pandas datetime series.

STEP 2: Use `np.arange` to create a temporary column `count` in `df` which acts as a unique counter for the rows in datframe, this helps keep track of the boundary conditions which can be helpful in distinguishing the next employee from the previous employee in the sorted dataframe.

```
# df
               Date_From    Date_To PROPOSAL_REASON  count
PERSON_NUMBER                                             
3720081000    2008-01-04 2009-12-07           MEINC      0
3720081000    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC      1
3720081000    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC      2
3720081018    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC      3
3720081018    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC      4
3720081077    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC      5
3720081111    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC      6
3720081211    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC      7
3720081211    2019-06-01 2019-10-31           MEINC      8
```

STEP 3: Create a boolean mask `m1` by subtracting "Date_From" from the shifted "Date_To" column then use [`Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) to get the number of days between the two columns then use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a boolean mask where truthy values corresponds to the condition where total days equal to `1`.

```
# m1
PERSON_NUMBER
3720081000    False
3720081000    False
3720081000     True
3720081018    False
3720081018     True
3720081077    False
3720081111     True
3720081211    False
3720081211    False
dtype: bool
```

STEP 4: Create a boolean mask `m2` using `Series.eq` and [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `level=0` where the truthy values corresponds to the boundary condition of the employee id.

```
# m2
PERSON_NUMBER
3720081000     True
3720081000    False
3720081000    False
3720081018     True
3720081018    False
3720081077     True
3720081111     True
3720081211     True
3720081211    False
Name: count, dtype: bool
```

STEP 5: Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select the scalar values from `OK` and `WARNING` based on the conditions `m1 | m2`:

```
# df1 (RESULT)
               Date_From    Date_To PROPOSAL_REASON CHECK_CONDITION
PERSON_NUMBER                                                      
3720081000    2008-01-04 2009-12-07           MEINC              OK
3720081000    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC         WARNING
3720081000    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC              OK
3720081018    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC              OK
3720081018    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC              OK
3720081077    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC              OK
3720081111    2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC              OK
3720081211    2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC              OK
3720081211    2019-06-01 2019-10-31           MEINC         WARNING
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation as well!

Comment: BTW that's a very nice question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['Date_From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_From'])
df['Date_To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_To'])
df['CHECK_CONDITION'] = (df['Date_From'] - df['Date_To'].shift()).dt.days != 1
print(df)

   PERSON_NUMBER  Date_From    Date_To PROPOSAL_REASON  CHECK_CONDITION
0     3720081000 2008-01-04 2009-12-07           MEINC             True
1     3720081000 2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC             True
2     3720081000 2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC            False
3     3720081018 2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC             True
4     3720081018 2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC            False
5     3720081077 2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC             True
6     3720081111 2019-04-01 2019-10-31           MEINC            False
7     3720081211 2018-07-01 2019-03-31           MEINC             True
8     3720081211 2019-06-01 2019-10-31           MEINC             True
```